# Sage CRM - Calling CustomCommunicationDetailBox screen with the Communication data and also the Comm_Link data

Tags: sage-crm

Im calling the `CommunicationSchedulingBox` screen in a custom .ASP page.

In this case the Communication entity have a relationship with Comm_Link table (Better said Comm_Link with Communication table)

When i load the .ASP page with the screen, i see all related data for the Communication entity (By doing this `EntityScreen.ArgObj = CurrentCommunication;`) but no Comm_Link data (`CmLi_Comm_UserId` field)

How can i show all the data for a Communication (And Comm_Link data) when calling the `CustomCommunicationDetailBox` screen in a custom ASP page?

I tried passing a second Record (Comm_Link in this case) to the Screen with `ArgObj` but does not work

The field is added in the screen:

[image]

When i call the screen with the Comm data in my asp page it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Check the view that the CustomCommunicationDetailBox screen is using. Does it contain CommLink data when you run the SQL?
E.g. if the view is vCommunication, can you see the Comm Link User when you run SELECT * FROM vCommunication WHERE comm_communicationid = *Id*?

Comment: Sorry i was calling `CommunicationSchedulingBox`. Ive updated the question. To answer your comment, if i check the screen (inside admin > Communication > Screen etc etc) the field is in the screen by default. How do i check which view is the screen using?

Comment: If i execute `SELECT CmLi_Comm_UserID, * FROM vCommunication WHERE comm_communicationid = 1471; ` for example, i see the value for the `CmLi_Comm_UserId` field

Comment: The Screen is using the `vCommunication` view, i just checked it in Admin > Customization > Communicaion > Screens > and click on the little grid to the right of the `CommunicationSchedulingBox` screen and then i see the associated view which is `vCommunication` with a foreign table `Comm_Link` and foreign colummn `CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId`